# Speed up data detector

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsdatadetector

I'm using an `NSDataDetector` to get an address from a string. I'm calling the method to do this around 500 times and it creates a noticeable lag (around 3 seconds on an iPhone 4). Is there any way to speed it up? I tried moving the data detector to a static variable, thinking the setup was taking time, but it made no difference. Here's the code:

```
- (NSDictionary *)addressDetectorForString:(NSString *)address
{
    if (!address) return nil;

    static NSDataDetector *addressDetector = nil;
    if (!addressDetector) {
        addressDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress error:nil];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = nil;

    NSArray* matches = [addressDetector matchesInString:address options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [address length])];
    if ([matches count] > 0) {
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) { // Only ever one result.
            if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeAddress) {
                dictionary = [match addressComponents];
            }
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: if you're extracting only the first result, why not using firstMatchInString:options:range: ?

Comment: Have you profiled and see which part is the most time consuming part?